# DB2 stored procedure razor sql

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, razorsql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in a DB2 database using RazorSQL Client but I'm getting this error:

> Blockquote
>   ERROR: A character, token, or clause is invalid or missing.
>   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SELECT

The stored procedure code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GENERAL.sp_checkemp
(IN emp_code VARCHAR(20))
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA


BEGIN

    SELECT "name_emp" FROM GENERAL."employee" WHERE "code_emp" = 'abc';

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` statements in the SQL PL context must have an `INTO` clause -- you have to put the query results somewhere. If your query returns more than one row, which I suspect it is, you must use a cursor instead.

Comment: You're right but my problem it's about tokens...how would you do it?